# Selecting from multiple columns with REGEX or LIKE

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex

I am trying to build a prepared statement string correct for a product search function and cannot for the life of me get it working to search multiple columns on a table

I find this code works for one column:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE `productTitle` REGEXP ?";

if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql))
{
    // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_term);

    $search_query = "";
    $temp = explode(" ", $_REQUEST["term"]);
    foreach ($temp as $tk=>$td)
    {
        $search_query .= (($tk > 0) ? " " : "");
        if (strpos($td, "-") !== false)
        {
            $search_query .= str_replace("-", "", $td);
        }
        else
        {
            $search_query .= $td;
        }
    }

    // Set parameters
    $param_term = '\\b' . $search_query . '\\b';

    // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
    if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt))
    {
        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    }
}
```

however i want to also search for the $search_query paramater of the REGEX in 2 other columns:

productBrand
productPart

i assumed this would work but it returns no results:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `product`
    WHERE `productTitle` REGEXP ?
       OR `productBrand` REGEXP ?
       OR `productPart` REGEXP ?";
```

with the ammended bind of:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $param_term, $param_term, $param_term);
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see what it has to do with mysqli or prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

Backslashes are a nuisance.  Possibly `\\b` turned into `\b` before it got to MySQL.  Try `\\\\b`.

Better yet, use a `FULLTEXT` index on the set of columns; `MATCH..AGAINST` will do a very efficient job of searching for *words*.